# Apply Result of NetTrain using GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'v trained a deep network (e.g. LeNet) using NetTrain with TargetDevice -> "GPU".  Everything works well and it is really fast.  But now I have a trained network and tens of thousands of samples to classify.  The GPU based training was evaluating ~ 1200 samples/second but seems like I can only use CPU based ParallelMap to evaluate trained network with samples (i.e. slow).

Is there a way to apply the trained network using the GPU as target device?

Comment: Not yet, but I hear gpu inference is coming in 11.1

Comment: Yes, we're trying to get it into 11.1, and will be available by writing `net[input, TargetDevice -> "GPU"]` instead of `net[input]`.

Comment: I cannot test the GPU at the moment, as I'm having issues with TargetDevice->"GPU" on my Quadro K2100M (compute capability 3.0, latest drivers) for some reason, but would love to know if this was added, as I was hoping to use it. It shouldn't be that difficult in theory, as this is done every single time a loss is computed for training data as well as for validation data.

Comment: Nevermind, just confirmed! It works in 11.1.

    trained[data,TargetDevice->"GPU"]

Answer (score 9):

Works in 11.1.

```
trained[data,TargetDevice->"GPU"]
```